# How to do a post method using a jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to make a simple post method using jquery ajax. Whenever I click submit button, Im getting an error:400(Bad request) in my console. Im not sure what is the mistake in the code, I will be happy if anyone helps with the issue. Thank you.

Note: The URL used in the code is a dummy and not a working URL.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            media="all" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ok(){
                var thisForm = $(this).closest('form.contactPage');
                var sendData = thisForm.serialize();
                jQuery.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                // url is dummy and not a working url
                 url: "dummy URL", 
                 data: thisForm.serialize(),
                    data: sendData,
                    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                    {

                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error){
                        console.log(error);
                    }
                })
            }            
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name="contactPage" class="form-email">

            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg input-sm validate-required" id="name" placeholder="Contact Person" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control input-lg bfh-countries wrapper-dropdown-2 validate-required" id="dd" data-country="US"></select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate-required" id="contactNum" placeholder="Contact Number" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate-required validate-email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="time" class="form-group form-control input-lg validate-required" id="time" placeholder="Time" />
            <input type="submit" class="form-group form-control" value="Contact" onclick="ok()" />
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: there is an issue with your url

Comment: ^^ `.sendMail` is not a valid TLD. Also, you've specified `data` twice (but that looks like it's an artifact of your trying to debug this, and it's harmless in loose mode, the second one wins).

Comment: The url is dummy. I haven't posted the personal url

Comment: @Rudhra: The standard thing to do in that case is show a relative URL (if you're using a relative URL), or a valid-looking `example.com` URL (if you're not using a relative URL).

Comment: Other than the duplication thing I mentioned above, the code looks fine. You'll have to debug why you're getting that response from the back end.

Comment: @Rudhra Try using Postman or any other REST Client, if the issue is reproducible from the Rest client too, then the issue is with the server-side  script. Also, check the Dev console -> Network and see how the data is being passed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Is there anyother way to try it.

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd do is a normal post to the target URL. Standard debugging: Isolate the problem.

Comment: Use fiddler. It is a great web debugging tool.

Comment: I have some questions to you: 1) What do you accepts at the backend url as data? 2) What do you want to send to the url? (JSON, String, ...) 3) Do you need a `Content-Type` as `application/json`?

Comment: I want to send the json to the url,  yes i need the content-type and application/json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            media="all" />
        <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/css/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
            type="text/css" media="all" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-formhelpers/2.3.0/js/bootstrap-formhelpers.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="contactPage" id="contactPage" class="form-email">

            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg input-sm validate-required" id="name" placeholder="Contact Person" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control input-lg bfh-countries wrapper-dropdown-2 validate-required" id="dd" data-country="US"></select>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate-required" id="contactNum" placeholder="Contact Number" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg validate-required validate-email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
            <input type="time" class="form-group form-control input-lg validate-required" id="time" placeholder="Time" />
            <input type="submit" class="form-group form-control" value="Contact"/>
        </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

     $(function(){
        $("#contactPage").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                    url:'url.php',
                    type:'POST',
                    data:$(this).serialize(),
                    success:function(result){
                       alert(result);
                    }
            });
        });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

That URL seems to invalid.

I suggest you check the URL given.

Answer (score 0):

The URL provided by you is not valid. try again with a valid URL..

Comment: check the code I have mentioned that url is dummy and not a working URL

Comment: @Rudhra change type: "POST" to type: "GET" and set dataType: "json". try this